# Use Pinterest API to upload video

Tags: java, api, video, pinterest

Can we use Pinterest API to upload Video ? , because the official documentation show only Post media of type Image .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But there is a workaround:

First, upload the video to youtube. Copy the thumbnail URL of this newly uploaded youtube video and pin it to Pinterest using the Pinterest API.

For example, if the youtube URL is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sqXRQhtqI8

then you can access the thumbnail by the following URL:
http://img.youtube.com/vi/1sqXRQhtqI8/0.jpg

To pin your video on Pinterest, pin the above URL with the Pinterest API.

Following pin is the result of pinning above video.
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/369084131956139919/

Comment: is this way still working? what is the endpoint for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a workaround to use animated Gifs - those are supported by using straight image_url parameter :) You can simply convert your video to a gif and post it.

Answer (score 1):

Pinterest has now added support for uploading videos through their api.

Noteworthy is that only business accounts can use this feature.

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/redoc/martech/#tag/Quick-Start:-Publish-Video